# Filter with where inside render json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have this in a controller:

```
def get_tags
  person = Person.where({fuid: params[:fuid]})
  render json: person, :only=>[:fuid], :include => [
    :hashtags => {
      :except => [:created_at, :updated_at],
      :methods => :person_count
    }
  ]
end
```

I am including hashtags but I need to filter those hashtags for only the ones that have `active = 1`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in the model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_hashtags,-> { where active: 1 }, class_name: 'Hashtags' 
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
render json: person :only=>[:fuid], :include => [
    :active_hashtags => {
      :except => [:created_at, :updated_at],
      :methods => :person_count
    }
  ]
```